# How to hide overflow in this example?

Tags: html, css

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/easeS/4/

Here is the html/css I have:

```
#main div
{
 float:left;
 width:30px;
 margin-right:10px;   
}
#main
{
 overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid;
}

<div id="main">
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
    <div>test3</div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why but it bumps the third div down to a new line instead of hiding it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. It fixes your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd div bumps down because there's not enough space for it to float.
Your 3 divs added up together (inc. margin) is equals to 120px;
The wrapper (#main) is 100px.
Therefore bumping the 3rd div down.

*If I understood your question correctly...*
What you want to do is hide it the 3rd div, for you to do this, you'd need to:
Add another wrapper div and give it a bigger width. Have a look at my [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/easeS/9/)

Comment: I think he need that the last `div` are put in a new line not at side of the last `div`.

Comment: Then no changes are needed. [His example](http://cl.ly/1m383F0s0o2U1s210245) is already putting it in a new line...

Comment: @Galled, no - this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AbeMiessler ah ok, I thought you was needed that each `div` were put in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add extra wrapping divs...

Try this instead:

```
#main div 
{
 display:inline;
 width:30px;
 margin-right:10px;   
}
#main
{
 overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Just changed the float rule to display: inline on the divs and added white-space: nowrap to #main.

Answer (score 0):

Is because your `div`s in your `div#main` are confined only to those dimensions specified in the style of `div#main`. To float to infinity and beyond, they need to have a space where to float. You can wrap your divs in a container with a very high height.

Try with this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/easeS/15/).